# Rust : futures::future::join_all(...).await runs futures sequentially but parallelism wanted

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await

I have the following `async` function (implementation is not important) :

```rust
async fn long_task(task_number: i32) {
    // do some long work
    println!("Task {} executed", task_number);
}
```

I want to run *n* times this function concurrently, so I defined this function :

```rust
async fn execute_long_tasks_async(n: i32) {
    let mut futures = Vec::new();
    for i in 1..=n {
        futures.push(long_task(i));
    }
    futures::future::join_all(futures).await;
}
```

I'm using the `join_all` function to wait until all tasks are executed. Then I call this function in my `main` :

```
fn main() {
    futures::executor::block_on(execute_long_tasks_async(3));
}
```

My issue is that the tasks are run sequentially :

```
Executing task 1
Task 1 executed
Executing task 2
Task 2 executed
Executing task 3
Task 3 executed
```

But I would have expect it runs concurrently, and I would get something like :

```
Executing task 1
Executing task 3
Executing task 2
Task 1 executed
Task 3 executed
Task 2 executed
```

Is there an alternative to `futures::future::join_all` to run all tasks in parallel ?

I'd like to use `await` to create a simple example demonstrating `async` and `await`.

Comment: "I have the following async function (implementation is not important) :" - Implementation IS important. AFAIK, `block_on` uses a single thread to execute. A Future runs until it is blocked on some `.await` or until it reaches the end. If there are no `.await`-s in your `async fn`, it never yields and does not allow other futures to execute until it is finished.

Answer (score 14):

`join_all` runs tasks concurrently (not parallel). It has the limitation that it can only switch between tasks when they yield. In addition that this it will always prefer to work on the first task if that one is not ready.

If your function is e.g. defined as

```rust
async fn long_task(task_number: i32) {
    println!("Executing Task {}", task_number);
    tokio::time::delay_for(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    println!("Task {} executed", task_number);
}
```

then the `await`/suspend point in the middle of the function will provide `join_all` with an opportunity to run the other functions/`Future`s - and you would observe the expected output.

However if `long_task` does not yield (e.g. because it would be thread-blocking), then this function would run to completion before other tasks start:

```rust
async fn long_task(task_number: i32) {
    println!("Executing Task {}", task_number);
    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    println!("Task {} executed", task_number);
}
```

If you have such functions they are in general not a good fit for the `async` world. `async` functions are intended not to be CPU intense and should not block the thread - so that other functions scheduled on the same executor can still run.

One alternative that might provide you a bit more parallelism is to use a multithreaded async runtime (e.g. tokio) and `spawn` each async function as a separate task. In that case the tasks could run on separate CPU cores and threads and wouldn't block each other that much. You can then use `join_all` on the collection of returned `JoinHandle`s to wait for all tasks to complete.